# Is The Artilleryman the same person as The Curate?

Tags: character-identification, war-of-the-worlds

We learn from H. G. Wells' novel *"The War of the Worlds"* that The Narrator meets, separately, The Curate and The Artilleryman after the Weybridge attack. The Artilleryman attempted to enter The Narrator's house, and The Curate became trapped inside a house with The Narrator. Two narrative scenes in the novel prompted me to ask the question:

- In chapter one "Under Foot" of book two "The Earth Under the Martians", The Narrator shares a bottle of beer with The Curate in the house where they sought shelter.

> "We sat in the adjacent kitchen in the dark—for we dared not strike a light—and ate bread and ham, and drank beer out of the same bottle."

- At the end of Chapter 9 "Wreckage" of the same book two, The Narrator mentions a beer bottle that he and The Artillerymen left.

> "I came down and went into the dining room. There were the mutton and the bread, both far gone now in decay, and a beer bottle overturned, just as I and the artilleryman had left them".

In addition, Harlan Ogilvy from the film *War of the Worlds* (2005) is a hybrid of the Curate and the Artilleryman.

Given this, I wonder if The Curate and The Artilleryman are the same person.

Comment: For the record, a curate is a type of vicar's assistant whereas a curator is someone who works in a museum

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The curate dies in Part 2, Chapter 4, which Wells entitled "The Death of the Curate".

The artilleryman reappears after that. He and the narrator recognize each other from their original meeting. Neither shows any sign that one of them conked the other one over the head to be taken by Martians.

There is every reason to take them as separate characters.

Comment: Maybe he's a zombie...